# Trying to detect speech using VAD(Voice Activity Detector)

Tags: python, pyaudio

I am able to read the audio but I am getting an error message while passing it to VAD(Voice Activity Detector). I think the error message is because the frames is in bytes, when feeding it to vad.is_speech(frame, sample_rate), should this frame be in bytes?
Here is the code below:

```
frame_duration_ms=10
duration_in_ms = (frame_duration_ms / 1000) #duration in 10ms
frame_size = int(sample_rate * duration_in_ms) #frame size of 160
frame_bytes = frame_size * 2

def frame_generator(buffer, frame_bytes):
    # repeatedly store 320 length array to the frame_stored when the frame_bytes is less than the size of the buffer
    while offset+frame_bytes < len(buffer):
        frame_stored = buffer[offset : offset+frame_bytes]
        offset = offset + frame_bytes
 return frame_stored
num_padding_frames = int(padding_duration_ms / frame_duration_ms)
# use deque for the sliding window
ring_buffer = deque(maxlen=num_padding_frames)
# we have two states TRIGGERED and NOTTRIGGERED state
triggered = True #NOTTRIGGERED state

frames = frame_generator(buffer, frame_bytes)

speech_frame = []
for frame in frames:
    is_speech = vad.is_speech(frame, sample_rate)
```

> Here is the error message:
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 16 speech_frame = []
> 17 for frame in frames:
> ---> 18     is_speech = vad.is_speech(frame, sample_rate)
> 19 #print(frames)
>
> C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\webrtcvad.py in
> is_speech(self, buf, sample_rate, length)
> 20
> 21     def is_speech(self, buf, sample_rate, length=None):
> ---> 22         length = length or int(len(buf) / 2)
> 23         if length * 2 > len(buf):
> 24             raise IndexError(
>
> TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it, you know `vad.is_speech(buf=frame, sample_rate)`, it takes the buf and calculates it length, but an integer value does not posses the `len()` attributes in python.
This throws an error for example:

```
num = 1
print(len(num))
```

Use this instead:

```
data = [1,2,3,4]
print(len(data))
```

So here is the correction to the code below:

```
frame_duration_ms=10
duration_in_ms = (frame_duration_ms / 1000) #duration in 10ms
frame_size = int(sample_rate * duration_in_ms) #frame size of 160
frame_bytes = frame_size * 2

values = []

def frame_generator(buffer, frame_bytes):
    # repeatedly store 320 length array to the frame_stored when the frame_bytes is less than the size of the buffer
    while offset+frame_bytes < len(buffer):
        frame_stored = buffer[offset : offset+frame_bytes]
        offset = offset + frame_bytes
        values.append(frame_stored)
 return values
num_padding_frames = int(padding_duration_ms / frame_duration_ms)
# use deque for the sliding window
ring_buffer = deque(maxlen=num_padding_frames)
# we have two states TRIGGERED and NOTTRIGGERED state
triggered = True #NOTTRIGGERED state

frames = frame_generator(buffer, frame_bytes)

frame = []
for frame in frames:
    is_speech = vad.is_speech(frame, sample_rate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import wave
import webrtcvad
# Initialize a vad object
audioFile = wave.open('ENG_M.wav')
framesAudio = audioFile.readframes(800)
#print(fraud.frames)

vad = webrtcvad.Vad()
# Run the VAD on 10 ms of silence and 16000 sampling rate 
sample_rate = 16000
frame_duration = 10  # in ms
for f in framesAudio :
    # Detecting speech
    final_frame = f.to_bytes(2,"big")* int(sample_rate * frame_duration / 1000)
    print(f'Contains speech: {vad.is_speech(final_frame, sample_rate)}')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.